# How can I make research with space on a edit text keyboard

Tags: android

I've developed a simple browser to research information on the net that has an edit text and a web view.
You can write the keywords in the edit text and press a button to reaserch your keywords on Google and see the results in the web view.

Now I wanna make possible to start the research using the space botton on the keyboard.

Is it possible? How can I do?

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

WebView web;
EditText adress;
String url = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv);
    adress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);
    web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    web.getSettings().getBuiltInZoomControls();

}

public void Research(View v) {

    url += adress.getText().toString();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Loading...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    web.loadUrl("https://www.google.it/search?q=" + url);
    url = "";
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.p:
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivityBookmarks.class));
            break;
        case R.id.r:
            web.reload();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Loading...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.b:
            if (web.canGoBack()) {
                web.goBack();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "You can't go more back!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;
        case R.id.f:
            if (web.canGoForward()) {
                web.goForward();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "You can't go more foward!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;
    }
    return false;
}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Override    
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (userPressedKey) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE) {
             adress.setText("");
             return true;
            }
        }
        super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```